# drop anonymous user in h2 database

Tags: h2

I currently use h2 database and started creating new users with different grants, but by default there is a user namen '' with the password '' in the database with all privilages, which is a security concern in my point of view.

So far i tried

```
drop user '';

delete FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USERS where name =''
```

But none of it worked so far. does anybody know the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User names are identifiers, not text literals. Identifiers are quoted with double quotes. So, try using double quotes:

```
drop user "";
```

Please note you can not drop the last administrator. If you only have one administrator, then you can not drop it. So you would need to create a second administrator first.